# Python Numba Jit only uses one core in Ubuntu Docker Container on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, pycharm, numba, ubuntu-20.04, windows-server-2019

I try to utilize all 8 cores with the following jited function that is supposed to return a Jaccard Distance Matrix:

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def compute_jaccard(session1, session2, arr, lengths):
    """Jited funciton to calculate jaccard distance
    """
    session1, session2 = session1[0], session2[0]
    intersection, union = 0, 0

    if(lengths[session2] > lengths[session1]):
        session1, session2 = session2, session1

    marked = np.zeros((lengths[session2],))

    for x in arr[session1][:lengths[session1]]:
        x_in_2 = arr[session2][:lengths[session2]] == x
        marked[x_in_2] = 1
        if(np.any(x_in_2)):
            intersection+=1
            union+=1
        else:
            union+=1

    union+=np.sum(marked==0)

    ## Use 1 - to get distances and not similarity
    jaccard = 1 - intersection/union

    return jaccard
```

When I run this code with Ubuntu on my physical machine, all cores are utilized which is why it shouldn't be a numba or code problem. However, I run a Ubuntu Docker Image using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2019 and the code only uses one CPU in this setting.

Additional Information:

- I run the Code using PyCharm on Windows and the Docker Plugin as Project Interpreter
- I tried to activate WLS2 but so far was not successful so I rely on Hyper-V
- The Python function multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns 8 cores
- Docker Desktop under stats shows that >700% of the CPU is used which is obviously weird but the Windows Resource Monitor shows that only one core is used

I tried the following things already:

- I activated Nested Virtualization
- I pass --cpuset-cpus 7 as Docker Parameter in PyCharm
- I tried the following Linux Images: Arch Linux, Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 20.10

What am I missing? Guesses where the problem lies (Windows Server 2019, Docker, Pycharm, Ubuntu (configuration) or Python code) would already help a lot..

Comment: Hi, did you solve it ?

Comment: No solution found on Windows Server 2019. I made it work on a linux based server though, so I guess it has something to do with Windows.